# Find zero eigenvalues of a dense positive semi-definite hermitian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a large dense positive semi-definite hermitian matrix, and it has many zero eigenvalues. How can I find these zero eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors efficiently without doing diagonalization? I have tried block Lanczos but it can only find a few zero eigenvalues unless I use a large Krylov space.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The eigenvectors associated to zero are just the elements of the Kernel of the  matrix. You just need to solve $AX=\vec{0}$.

Comment: @Daniel, thank you for the answer. The problem is, matrix A is too large, and I can not store it. All I know is the vector Ax that matrix A acting on arbitrary vector x. In this case, how can I get all the solutions for AX = 0? Is there any advanced algorithm for this problem?